# Loop to insert image in Vba

Tags: vba

I would like to copy images to a template file so that each image is copied to a template file.

1-Open the model file

2-Copy image1

3-Save and close the template file

4- Repeat for each image in the folder

The macro that I use allows to do it for an image. However I therefore wish to make a loop for each image in the folder.

Here is the code I use:

```
Sub Insert_Image()

Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
Dim Fichier As String

'On Error Resume Next

Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WordApp.Visible = True
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open("C:\Template_Files.docx") 'open template file Word
WordDoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture Filename:="C:\MesImages\Image1.png" Image to Insert

On Error GoTo 0

With WordDoc.InlineShapes(1)
.ConvertToShape
End With

With WordDoc.Shapes(1)
.ZOrder msoBringInFrontOfText 'image in front of the text
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you looking to insert all images in the same document?

Comment: no, I need to add one image per document. Thanks